# Undefined index: command in C:\wamp64\www\WSMshop\products.php on line 5

Tags: php

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
        $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
        addtocart($pid,1);
        header("location:shoppingcart.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Notice: Undefined index: command in C:\wamp64\www\WSMshop\products.php on line 5
and that's the error, i do what i know can fix it, but nothing happen. Please help me. im still newbie in this. TIA

Answer (score -2):

Since too little code is provided - my suggestion is to simply make additional check whether the 'command' is being submit by changing the if statement to:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks ^_^, i'll try.

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
  remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
 }
 else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST=='clear'){
  unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 }
 else if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
  $max=count($_SESSION['cart']); //my error is here
  for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
   $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
   $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
   if($q>0 && $q<=999){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
   }
   else{
    $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';